# function of functions in python

Tags: python

I want to repeat the code from `calculateForce` onwards 5 times, whilst feeding back in the results i.e. feeding position and position1 back into the loop. I think I might want to write a function of a function but I have never done this before and I am not sure how to do it.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np
G = 10
t=5

class Particle:
    def __init__(self,mass):
        self.mass = mass
        self.position = np.array([0,0],int)

    def update():
        for x in range():   

        def calculateForce(self,other):
            Force = (G*self.mass*other.mass)/(other.position - self.position)**2
            print(Force)
            return(Force)

        def calculateAcceleration(self,Force): 
            acceleration = (Force/self.mass)    
            print('Acceleration of particle is', acceleration)
            return acceleration   

        def calculateAcceleration1(other, Force):
            acceleration1 = (Force/other.mass)
            print('Acceleration of particlce is', acceleration1)
            return acceleration1        

       def calculateVelocity(self):
           velocity = (acceleration*t)
           print('Velocity of particle is', velocity)
           return velocity

      def calculateVelocity1(self):
          velocity1 = (acceleration1*t)
          print('Velocity of particle1 is', velocity1)
          return velocity1

      def calculatePosition(self):
         position = (velocity*t)
         print('Position of particle is', position)
         return position

      def calculatePosition1(self):
         position1 = (velocity1*t)
         print('Position of particle1 is', position1)
         return position1

p = Particle(10)
p1 = Particle(20)       
p1.position[0] = 5 
p1.position[1] = 5 
print(p1.position)
Force = p.calculateForce(p1)
acceleration = p.calculateAcceleration(Force)
acceleration1 = p1.calculateAcceleration1(Force)
velocity = p.calculateVelocity()
velocity1 = p.calculateVelocity1()
position = p.calculatePosition()
position1 = p.calculatePosition1()
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your indentation, please, fix it

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question, you want to recursively call calculateForce 5 times?

Comment: i would like to calculate the force given mass and position of two particles. then from this calculate their acceleration, from this calculate their velocity and from this calculate their position.  then i want to go back to the beginning of the calculation and feed the new positions into calculateForce and repeat this 5 times.  advancing by t=5 each time. i am trying to model the interaction of two particles under gravity in two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on recursion and iteration, in the form of a function to which you can pass you designated function (e.g. calculateForce, calculateAcceleration, etc):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv


def myf(value):
    return value*2


class C(object):
    def myf2(self, value):
        return value*3


def pump_rec(times, funct, value):
    print "pump_rec: ", times, funct.__name__, value
    if times > 1:
        return funct(pump_rec(times-1, funct, value))
    else:
        return funct(value)


def pump_iter(times, funct, value):
    while times > 0:
        print "pump_iter: ", times, funct.__name__, value
        value = funct(value)
        times -= 1
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) < 3:
        print "usage: %s times value" % (argv[0],)
        exit(1)
    print pump_rec(int(argv[1]), myf, int(argv[2]) )
    print pump_iter(int(argv[1]), myf, int(argv[2]) )
    obj = C()
    print pump_rec(int(argv[1]), obj.myf2, int(argv[2]) )
    print pump_iter(int(argv[1]), obj.myf2, int(argv[2]) )
```

Running it with

```
python fof.py 3 1
```

produces

```
pump_rec:  3 myf 1
pump_rec:  2 myf 1
pump_rec:  1 myf 1
8
pump_iter:  3 myf 1
pump_iter:  2 myf 2
pump_iter:  1 myf 4
8
pump_rec:  3 myf2 1
pump_rec:  2 myf2 1
pump_rec:  1 myf2 1
27
pump_iter:  3 myf2 1
pump_iter:  2 myf2 3
pump_iter:  1 myf2 9
27
```